# Composable looks focus when item inside a lazy list and is clicked

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My layout contains a combination of lazy row and lazy column which has a card inside it.When I click on the card once it attains focus, i click on it and onFocusChang event is triggered giving hasFocus as false but card composable does not call anything thats focusable.What could be wrong?